# Invoke local python script from web browser instance

Tags: python, browser

Am working on a python script (env: custom Linux Mint 17.1) that uses a webbrowser class to instantiate a browser instance that renders some HTML.
I'd like to have a hyperlink within the HTML, which when clicked upon, causes 
a *local* python script to run.

Have not found any precise way to do this.. any help is appreciated,
TIA, Kaiwan.

Comment: Overload the method invoked on a link click in your `webbrowser` class and invoke the script from the overloaded function.

Comment: Thanks Iskren ; I'm a newbie at Python ;could you please point me to some code that implements this (or similar), thanks..Also, don't know if it's relevant, but I should mention that the Web browser class am using is imported..

Comment: Current code snippet : import webbrowser
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
STATIC_ROOT = "./bootstrap.min.css"
web.load(QUrl( "./pop.html"))
web.show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using PyQt4 and the QtWebKit module, it's very easy to do so.

You create a function that grabs the url and acts accordingly.
Here's some sample code to get you started:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView, QWebPage
import sys


def linkHandler(url):
    print "[DEBUG] Clicked link is: %s" % url
    if url == "My Triggering URL":
        print "Found my link, launching python script"
    else:
        # Handle url gracefully
        pass



def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    webview = QWebView()
    # Tell our webview to handle links, which it doesn't by default
    webview.page().setLinkDelegationPolicy(QWebPage.DelegateAllLinks)
    webview.linkClicked.connect(linkHandler)
    webview.load(QUrl('http://google.com'))
    webview.show()
    return app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

P.S. Whenever you're posting code snippets, it's better to edit your question and provide the information there because it becomes a mess in the comment field.
P.S.S. Be more specific in your tags the next time, there are a lot of frameworks that can actually create a browser, PyQt4 would be a very good tag to begin with and would get you more answers.